# Playing and Recording in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am implementing the application in Blackberry in which I start two threads, one thread constantly receives the UDP packets from the network and stores them in one common queue, another thread is of my player which playes data from this common queue. But in this implementation I some time get the data played, some time getting ControlledAccessException and sometime error 5. So what can be the reason?????

Any help.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ControlledAccessException can be thrown if you application doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform a certain operation.  Go to the application settings and make sure everything is set to "allow" and see if that helps.

As for error 5 - if you're talking about an error thrown by the audio player (received by the PlayerListener), you can refer to [this page](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Error-code-8-when-trying-to-start-an-rtsp-audio-stream/m-p/127902#M14537) for a reference on what the numeric error codes mean.

Comment: I am using Blackberry simulator, so I think there is no option in simulator.....I want to make VOIP client so actually where to start I am not getting that....Help if you know about this.....